# Spark streaming performance degradation when upgrading from 1.3.0 to 1.6.0

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm working with a Spark streaming application that reads avro messages from Kafka and process them. The batch time of the streaming is 20 seconds.

I had an application running on Spark 1.3.0 with a scheduling delay of each batch to 0 ms but now after upgrading to Spark 1.6.0 I see that the scheduling delay goes up and the processing time of a single batch takes more time.

Processing time is increasing due to the upgrade of the Spark version but the application is running with the same configurations and the same rate of received message.

From the Spark web UI I can see that the operation that seems to take a lot of time is a map over a DStream object. It looks strange to me because it is not a particular heavy operation.

Has anyone noticing the same issue upgrading spark and spark-streaming to 1.6.0 ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've noticed that spark 1.6.0 works with a different memory management. In order to use old memory management schema I pass LegacyMode to true in spurk-submit but I'm still observing that the application does not works properly in terms of performance.